# Nested tabs display in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I'm trying to include several tabs into an existing tab, it works but I have a display problem when I try to display the tab containing the nested tabs.
When I click on it, the content of all the children tabs are displayed instead of the first tab only.
Here is a link to check the problem:
http://www.bootply.com/3hWg0EDCmx

I can't find where I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong css class assigned to tab-memory and tab-activity. 'tab-io' should have the class "tab-pane fade in active", while the rest should have "tab-pane fade in".

Here is the link to the working code: http://www.bootply.com/3hWg0EDCmx#